# Backend routing based on cookie name substring

Tags: haproxy

Example cookie name in request:

```
wordpress_logged_in_8df6736080e8...
```

I want to create an haproxy acl based on when the cookie name begins with `wordpress_logged_in` and then route the logged in users based on that acl to separate backend.

Answer (score 1):

```
acl url_admin path_beg -i /wp-admin /wp-login.php
acl url_admin hdr_sub(cookie) wordpress_logged_in
```

This config is working for me, as it matches the whole cookie header and some URLs. Without the first ACL it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [cook_beg](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#7.3.6-cook) for the acl

```
acl cookie_backend cook_beg(wordpress_logged_in) -m found
...
use_backend cookie_backend if cookie_backend
...
default_backend default_backend
```

This Blog post explains the haproy acl [Introduction to HAProxy ACLs](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls/)
In the doc can you find more details [Using ACLs to form conditions](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#7.2)

Comment: Sadly it's not working, because cookie name is "wordpress_logged_in_<HASH>". LOGGED_IN_COOKIE is a PHP constant which doesn't appear anywhere in the request.

Comment: Ah okay. I have adopted the answer with your comment